# check the parent div has the div with child class

Tags: html, css

I want to check the parent div has the div given class.I have the parent div '.parent'.I want to check  this parent have the div with class '.child' in css.Is it possible in css.I have acheived this using

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
     test
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery but I want to check it in css

Comment: You mean you want to check if parent div has child class?

Comment: ya  absolutely as u tell.

Comment: What do you want to do with that information? You could set styles on the child container based on whether it is inside a parent div, but that's about it in css. Css has a 'direct descendant' selector `>` and a 'sibling' selector `+`, and plenty of others, but no 'parent' selector I'm afraid.

Comment: I want to set style for parent

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's possible to check using [**`CSS :empty selector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) as below,

> The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at
>   all.

If it has any `child element` or text node then `background` style remains `blue` else if it's `empty` then `background` style changes to `red`.

```css
.parent{
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.parent:empty{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
     test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3386779 This could be easiest way to check using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

try this one for more details

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

```
.parent:has('.child')
{
properties
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but not supported anywhere [**:has#Browser_compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent .child
{
   /*Your style under child div*/
}

.parent
{
   // Style under all matched with parent
}
```

you can try like this.
Eventually it apply only when child class is found.