# How can I use CSS to make a div invisible when there are no divs with a specific class under it?

Tags: css, reactive

I want to use CSS to hide entire groups of items when they don't have a threshold of named div items inside of them. I have 6 sections of faq 'questions', and a filtering mechanism that shows/hides these questions according to matching search terms. If after a search one or more of these sections does not have visible questions in it I don't want that section to be visible (ie. `display: none;`)

Is it possible to accomplish this purely with CSS? So that the jquery-driven reactive page search can rely on CSS to hide faq sections that don't have matching results inside of them? I have a general idea of how I'd accomplish this with JS, is it possible to do only using CSS?

To give an idea of what I'm thinking, I'd have:

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="question" style="display: none;">
    Question goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'd like to use CSS to apply something (`display: none;` or otherwise) to make the entire "group" invisible BECAUSE every div with the CSS class of 'question' is not visible from the `display: none;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039194/check-the-parent-div-has-the-div-with-child-class check this `:empty` selector will do the job

Comment: you can call the parent element to call the specific div that you want to hide like .group > div.question {display:none}. In your case its seems like you want to have a capabilities of hiding on specific instances I would call an ID or add an additional class in it.In jquery you can use the .find() then execute which one you want to hide.

Answer (score 2):

Based on answer in

[check the parent div has the div with child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039194/check-the-parent-div-has-the-div-with-child-class)

You can control your divs if it is empty using `.question:empty`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}


body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.group{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap:1rem;
}

.question{
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  display: grid;
  /* display:none; you can change this */
  place-content: center;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.question:empty {
  display:block;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
 <div class="group">
        <div class="question">
          <p>Question</p>
        </div>
        <div class="question"></div>
        <div class="question">
          <p>Question</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

---

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

The thing that you need is about selecting parent element. There is one actually which is `:has` pseudo class but still experimental. But i create a scenerio for you.

While you are applying inline `style = display: none;` in .question divs you can also apply them `type="hidden"`

and others which have question inside(visible divs) `type:not-hidden`

```
<div class="group">
      <div class="question" style="display: none" type="hidden"></div>
      <div class="question" type="not-hidden"></div>
      <div class="question" style="display: none" type="hidden" ></div>
    </div>
<div class="group">
      <div class="question" style="display: none" type="hidden"></div>
      <div class="question" style="display: none" type="hidden"></div>
      <div class="question" style="display: none" type="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Then u can use

```
.group{
  display:none;
}
.group:has(div[type="not-hidden"]) {
  display: block;
}
```

kind of selector(`.group:has(div[type="not-hidden"])`) to get the parent which has a child div have `type="not-hidden";` then you can apply parent a `display:block` to get visible.

`:has` pseudo class only supported in Safari. Maybe you can try to check this in Safari.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Will css :empty selector work for a `class="question"` section that in fact has elements inside of it that are all marked with `display=none`? I'm not selecting elements that are empty, and I want to hide the entire group iff there are no questions in it that are visible.